# Are there alternatives to Adobe Creative Suite?

Tags: software-recommendation

This is a question mainly about design packages such as Adobe Creative Suite -- Is there another "create suite" style package out there that rivals Adobe CS?

I know there are programs such as GIMP or Corel Draw that are good alternative to Photoshop/Illustrator, but are there any actual "whole" packages out there like Adobe CS, be it small or big that delivers multiple programs for tasks such as: Photo editing, vector work, animation, 3d, etc?

Will Adobe CS always be crowned as the top, all round package for designs to use or will there be a new suite in the future that's regarded as the "go-to" package?

Comment: @Ryan I understand it is partially speculative but I also ask the question as to understand other what other option are available for designers.

Comment: Then ask that question? As it stands though I don't think its a good fit, might just be me. Its kinda like going onto money.stackexchange.com and asking if Google will always be a high performing stock.

Comment: @Ryan I understand. I have edited my question .

Comment: Nope. We are still fully in their death grip. At least for the near future. Things could change slowly and then suddenly though